# How do I translate this C# line for doing a RegEx.replace to VB

Tags: vb.net, regex

sTitle = Regex.Replace(sTitle, @"&\w+;", "")

Comment: That's not valid C# to start with. There's a `c` at the end of the string literal...

Comment: I fixed that. I had added that as one of my attempts to make it works. It looks like I can just remove the @ and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sTitle = Regex.Replace(sTitle, "&\w+;", "")
```